# ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http already installed

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am new on Ionic Mobile application development, so I am trying to POST data from Ionic app. Whenever I have run the app in browser using

> ionic cordova run browser

It display below issue in console,

> Native: tried calling HTTP.post, but the HTTP plugin is not installed.
>
> Install the HTTP plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http'.

I have installed same plugin using terminal but terminal give warnings as its already installed.
[image]

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/ you also need to run

`npm install --save @ionic-native/http`

and referencing it correctly in your app, please take a look at above link

Also for running app in browser try below command

`Ionic serve`

Comment: Hi @RezaRahmati, I have follow the same thing and run the same command. But still have same error.

Comment: @Piyush run `Ionic serve` and see what is the result

Comment: Its working if I run "Ionic serve" command. But Http post not working.

Comment: Display "cordova_not_available" message.

Comment: @Piyush This error happens when running in browser and using plugins, so simply ignore the error, if there is close button click that and continue your work. Just be aware for testing plugins you need to run it on device or emulator

Comment: @Piyush BTW for simple POST request you don't need any plugins or ionic-native , see this video
https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-send-data-with-post-requests-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/1975

The issue appears to have been fixed but there might be a lag in updating npm

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem and I solve it with uninstall and reinstall the plugin

Uninstall plugin completely

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-advanced-http
npm uninstall @ionic-native/http
```

and reinstall it

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
npm install @ionic-native/http
```

Answer (score 0):

The Native Http plugin is the only way to handle the CORS from the client-side.

The way I see your problem, there might two possible fixes

1. Check whether the plugin is called after the platform.ready().
2. Even after it, if doesn't work or show the same error then follow this method.

   ```
   // Declare cordova as a global constant
   declare const cordova;

   // directly call the cordova pulgin using "cordova.pulgin.http"

   cordova.plugin.http.post(apiUrl, {}, {},
   response => {},
   response => {})
   ```